# How to open a document in a new window in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Sometimes I would like to undock a source file and slide it over to another monitor while editing another file.  How do you do this in Visual Studio 2008?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. It's a new feature of VS 2010 (Finally ;))
If you don't need any plugins and IDE extensions (i.e. Resharper) just download Visual studio 2010 beta.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can do that in Visual Studio 2008.

You can do it in Visual Studio 2010: you right-click on the document's tab and click "Float".  Not that that helps you much. 8-)

Answer (score 0):

In your solution explorer

right click >> open with >> add

Browse to the visual studio exe (devenv.exe) to add it to the open with list

Now when you choose 'open with visual studio' it will open it in a new instance that you can drag to your other screen

Comment: I think it's not a good solution - every time you edit that file you will get irritating prompt that sth has been changed outide IDE

Answer (score -1):

Tools->Options->Multiple Documents may be a good starting point?

Comment: Under Environment->General (the default)